# Returning times between other times

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables `AVAIL` and `AVAIL_TIMES`.  `AVAIL` contains avail_id, avail_date, open_flag.  `AVAIL_TIMES` contains avail_times_id, Avail_id, Start_Time, End_time.  All date and time fields are typed as DATE

If a date is flagged in the avail open_flag column it means that the facility is open for that date, but the times it is open is listed in avail_times.  There can be multiple time ranges for a particular day.

I need to return a list of times it is not open for that day.

For Example (one day of many)

Open times for day:

```
Start_time: 08:00 End_time 10:00
Start_time: 12:00 End_time 14:00
Start_time: 15:00 End_time 17:00
```

I want it to return something like:

```
00:00 - 07:59
10:01 - 11:59
14:01 - 14:59
17:01 - 23:59
```

I think I would be able to work through this with a temporary table and some plsql logic, but ideally this would be a pure sql solution.

Comment: What is the exact structure of the two tables? "Structure" means column names AND THEIR DATA TYPES. You may leave out some columns if they have no relevance to your question. So, for example: Are there two columns, START_TIME and END_TIME, in your table? Are they VARCHAR2 (terrible choice!) data type, or are they DATE (perfect!) data type? Then: in the second table, why do you want the first row to be from 00:00 to 07:59, and not to 08:00? Or the next one from 10:01 and not from 10:00? That is weird and illogical.

Comment: Edited to say that all date and time fields are typed as DATE.  I want them to the minute before so that someone could still schedule an appointment at 8:00.  It's not illogical as I see it.  Why would I want it until 08:00 if it is open at 08:00?  If that makes the solution easier, then ok, but I'll have to account for it elsewhere somehow.

Comment: Time is on a continuum, not discrete steps (like integers 1, 2, 3, 4, ...). If an interval is from 00:00 to 07:59 and the next one is from 08:00 to 10:00, where does 07:59:30 fall?  (30 seconds before 8 o'clock). In almost all cases, with time intervals you are much better off matching the end of one interval and the beginning of the next interval. For example: in a simple computation, you will show the space is not available for 7 hours and 59 minutes at the beginning of the day. That's wrong: it is not available for 8 hours, not for 7 hours and 59 minutes.

Comment: Another question: can the available times span over midnight (22:00 to 04:00 of the next day) or perhaps even over several days? Or are the intervals, in such cases, already subdivided into the intervals that fall in each calendar day?

Comment: No, all start and end times for that ID will be on the same day.

Comment: Your data is set up specifically to record periods where a facility IS available.  And yet you're coding to find out when a store IS NOT available.  Listing the available  times is simple.  Listing times where a facility is NOT available is always going to be harder.  Is there any way your requirements could be modified?  For example if you're trying to validate an appointment request, writing a function that returns available / unavailable given a specific date / time would be simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure how you want to input the date of interest (I used a bind variable, passed in as a string - but that may not be the right way for you, perhaps you want to join to your other table, etc.) - or the exact output you want. In any case, the query below demonstrates the "core" of the code you need to achieve this kind of output from the inputs.

```
alter session set nls_date_format='mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi';

with
     avail_times ( start_time, end_time ) as (
       select to_date('06/20/2017 08:00'), to_date('06/20/2017 10:00') from dual union all
       select to_date('06/20/2017 12:00'), to_date('06/20/2017 14:00') from dual union all
       select to_date('06/20/2017 15:00'), to_date('06/20/2017 17:00') from dual
     )
select   trunc(min(start_time)) as start_time, min(start_time) as end_time
  from   avail_times
  where  trunc(start_time) = to_date(:input_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
union all
select   end_time, 
         lead(start_time, 1, trunc(start_time) + 1) over (order by start_time)
  from   avail_times
  where  trunc(end_time) = trunc(start_time)
order by start_time
;

START_TIME        END_TIME
----------------  ----------------
06/20/2017 00:00  06/20/2017 08:00
06/20/2017 10:00  06/20/2017 12:00
06/20/2017 14:00  06/20/2017 15:00
06/20/2017 17:00  06/21/2017 00:00
```

Comment: Very cool.  Thank you.  It's not exactly what I needed, but it will get me there.

Answer (score 0):

Another Approach. Hope this helps.

```
SELECT ID,
  START_TME,
  END_TM,
  DIFF_TM
FROM
 --Not part of SQL just to simulate the table data
  (WITH TMP AS
  (SELECT 1 ID,
    TO_DATE('06/27/2017 00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') START_TME,
    TO_DATE('06/27/2017 08:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') END_TM
  FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 ID,
    TO_DATE('06/27/2017 10:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') START_TME,
    TO_DATE('06/27/2017 15:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') END_TM
  FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 ID,
    TO_DATE('06/27/2017 16:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') START_TME,
    TO_DATE('06/27/2017 17:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') END_TM
  FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 id,
    to_date('06/27/2017 17:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') start_tme,
    TO_DATE('06/27/2017 18:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') END_TM
  FROM DUAL
  )
  --SQL start from here
SELECT TMP.*,
  LEAD(START_TME) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY 1 DESC) next_st_tm,
  LEAD(END_TM) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY 1 DESC) NEXT_EN_TM,
  EXTRACT( HOUR FROM TO_TIMESTAMP(LEAD(START_TME) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY 1 DESC),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'))- EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TO_TIMESTAMP(end_tm,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')) DIFF_TM
FROM TMP
ORDER BY 1 ,
  2
  )
WHERE DIFF_TM <> 0;
```